# How to prove $|e^{x_1} -e^{x_2}| \leq \frac{1}{2} |x_1 -x_2|(e^{x_1} +e^{x_2})$?

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

How to prove  $|e^{x_1} -e^{x_2}| \leq  \frac{1}{2} |x_1 -x_2|(e^{x_1} +e^{x_2})$? Should we use the convexity of exponent function and its derivative?

Answer (score 6):

You have, if $x_1>x_2$,\begin{align}\frac{\left|e^{x_1}-e^{x_2}\right|}{\left|x_1-x_2\right|}&=\frac{e^{x_1}-e^{x_2}}{x_1-x_2}\\&=\int_0^1\exp\left((1-\lambda)x_1+\lambda x_2\right)\,\mathrm d\lambda\text{ (change of variable)}\\&\leqslant\int_0^1(1-\lambda)e^{x_1}+\lambda e^{x_2}\,\mathrm d\lambda\text{ (since $\exp$ is convex)}\\&=e^{x_1}\int_0^11-\lambda\,\mathrm d\lambda+e^{x_2}\int_0^1\lambda\,\mathrm d\lambda\\&=\frac{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}2.\end{align}The case in which $x_1<x_2$ is similar and the case in which $x_1=x_2$ is trivial.

Comment: How does the inequality follow?

Comment: @max_zorn $\left|\frac{e^{x_1}-e^{x_2}}{x_1-x_2}\right|\leqslant\frac{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}2\iff|e^{x_1}-e^{x_2}|\leqslant\frac12|x_1-x_2|(e^{x_1}+e^{x_2})$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the detail!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your argument? I don’t think convexity is enough to conclude $e^x\le (e^{x_1}+e^{x_2})/2$. Perhaps we can also show $x\le (x_1+x_2)/2$?

Comment: @Victor It was indeed wrong. Very much so. What do you think now?

Comment: Very nice! I’m glad to see there is indeed a way to use convexity here.