# Midpoint inequality for exponential

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

I want to show that $$|e^x - e^y|\le \frac12|x-y|(e^x+e^y)$$ for all real $x,y$. Here is one approach: for $x<y$ (resp. $y<x$), the mean value theorem provides $z\in(x,y)$ (resp. $z\in(y,x)$) satisfying $$\frac{e^x-e^y}{x-y}=e^z.$$ By convexity, it suffices to show $z\le\frac12(x+y)$. Can this be carried out? The answer in [How to prove $|e^{x_1} -e^{x_2}| \leq \frac{1}{2} |x_1 -x_2|(e^{x_1} +e^{x_2})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591526/how-to-prove-ex-1-ex-2-leq-frac12-x-1-x-2ex-1-ex-2) uses convexity directly, without the mean value theorem—-are there any conceptually different arguments?

Comment: Since I have corrected my answer, perhaps that you could edit your question, eliminating what you wrote about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=y+h,$ with $h>0.$ The inequality is equivalent to $$ e^h-1\le {1\over 2}h(e^h+1)$$ and consequently to $$2(e^h-1)\le h(e^h+1)$$ In view of the MacLaurin expansion we are after $$ 2h+2\sum_{n=2}^\infty {h^n\over n!}\le 2h +\sum_{n=1}^\infty {h^{n+1}\over n!}\\ =2h+\sum_{n=2}^\infty n{h^{n}\over n!}$$ The last inequality is obvious as $2\le n.$